# ubuntu 16.04.3/kde/plasma: ON BOOT-ethernet up but not connected; wifi up sometimes

Tags: networking, kde, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 with low-latency kernel, running KDE plasma.

On each boot ethernet is always up even when not connected; wifi is up sometimes.

I must disable the phantom ethernet connection to get wifi to work!

My Dell Inspirion 1525 laptop uses broadcom wifi. I used Ask's install instructions the put the specific broadcom device drivers in the lowlatency kernel. Before that no wifi, just ethernet (whether wire connected or not). Now I get ethernet (whether wire connected or not) and wifi.

On boot, I use the widget to show network connections and then close *enp9s0* (It shows the wired connection listed as `ifupdown` which I installed several months ago because ethernet was always up, but problem remained. I deleted the original default ethernet named connection in "connection editor") I can bring *enp9s0* up or down with no actual wired connection. `ifupdown` automatically recognizes if the wired connection is inserted to the laptop and I thought it would "know" at boot time what was actually connected to ethernet. It does not.

My */etc/network/interfaces* file is:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback


#---   enp9s0   ---was eth0------

allow-hotplug enp9s0

iface enp9s0 inet static

  address 192.168.99.10

  netmask 255.255.255.0

  gateway 192.168.99.1


#--- wlp12s0  ---was wlan0------

auto wlp12s0

iface wlp12s0 inet static

  address 192.168.99.11

  netmask 255.255.255.0 

  gateway 192.168.99.1

  wpa-ssid Disco

  wpa-psk pre-shared-key
```

The interfaces file is used for the IP addresses, so the problem may be here, but I do not know what would be correct.

================================

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]

plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono

dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]

managed=true
```

==========================

```
 lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)

00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)

00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)

00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)

09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)

0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please update your post with contents of */etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf* and *lspci*.

Comment: N0rbert: Thanks for your attention. I tried adding auto enp9s0 to the /etc/network/interfaces but it did nothing. Same results as before.

Comment: I think you should set `managed=false` (below `[ifupdown]` in */etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf*).